# JSON.stringify an object with a blob

Tags: javascript, json, libsox

I have an object with an audio blob inside of it. When I call JSON.stringify on the object, the blob disappears. How to stringify a binary blob in an object ?

The audio blob is from [the sox-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sox-element) and in this case is of mime type 'audio/wav'.

```
let blob = this/soxElem.getBlob();
let object = {
  audio: blob,
  name: "hi"
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
```

The console shows {audio:{}, name: "hi"}. The blob is gone.

Comment: Maybe base64 encode it

Comment: it may be, blob is a datatype and you are returning string datatype

Comment: The blob isn't gone, it just is an object that has no enumerable properties: `{}`. What result do you expect? JSON has no type for binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert to an array which JSON can handle :

```
let ab = await this.soxElem.getBlob().arrayBuffer();
let object = {
  audio: Array.from(new Uint8Array(ab)),
  name: "hi"
}
```

On the receiving side (e.g. with Node.js) decode it like so :

```
let binaryData = Buffer.from(data.audio);
```

Comment: If it's to send that data to a server they'd be better sending it as multipart from the beginning. This encoding to JSON will be even bigger than a base64 encoding which is already ~37% bigger than the binary data it represents.

Comment: What do you think is a btter way ?